# Pandas iterate over row AND cell in the row and append new row to a new df

Tags: python, pandas

How do I check for multiple items in a cell, and then if they are there, go through them and put each one on a new line in a new df?

Starting with a CSV

```
Computer Name, IP Address
host1    192.168.5.2\n192.168.5.3\n192.168.5.4\n
host2   192.168.5.5
```

I know how to open and turn the second column into a list in the cell, but how do I use pandas to iterate over the new column and then create a new df?

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=["Computer Name","IP Address"])
print(df.iloc[:2])
df['EventItem'] = df['IP Address'].str.split("\n")
df = pd.DataFrame(df,columns=["Computer Name","EventItem"])
```

gives me ...

```
Computer Name, EventItem
host1    [192.168.5.2,192.168.5.3,192.168.5.4]
host2   [192.168.5.5]
```

Not gonna lie, I'm kinda lost on how to get this to

```
host1   192.168.5.2
host1   192.168.5.3
host1   192.168.5.4
host2   192.168.5.5
```

I'd appreciate any suggestions... thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After that `split` do `explode`

```
df = df.explode('EventItem')
```